# How do I call a stored procedure in MySQL from python?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

I am trying to call a stored procedure made in MySQL from python, the code I show below does not give me an error, but it does nothing. I tried calling the "SP" from MySQL and it works correctly, so the problem is in my Python code, I hope someone can help me complete my code

```
def MultMont(self,N,Miemb,Uni):
    cnx=self.Connect()
    Cursor=cnx.cursor()
    Cursor.execute("CALL mult_mont '"+N+"','"+Miemb+"','"+Uni+"')")
    cnx.commit()
    self.CloseConnection(cnx)
```

Comment: This link might help http://www.mysqltutorial.org/calling-mysql-stored-procedures-python/

Answer (score 0):

I used callproc in MySQL:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-callproc.html

```
cnx=self.Connect()
Cursor=cnx.cursor()    
params = ['"+N+"','"+Miemb+"','"+Uni+"']
Cursor.callproc(mult_mont, params)
```